# Custard-like cake

Tags: baking

I would like to cook finger food for my one year old. I am looking for a recipe for a soft cake-- something like a loose cheesecake or set custard in terms of consistency. I did make a bread pudding serving the middle portion to him, but I would like to avoid using so much bread or flour. I would adapt the recipe to accommodate savory vegetables or do a low sugar, or no sugar, option when using it for fruits. Anyone know the name of a bread/cake/tart that would come close to what I am after?

Comment: We're not a recipe sharing site, but maybe someone can identify a type of cake that would fit the bill, which you could adapt.

Comment: I don't have it in front of me but one of our baby cookbooks included something called (IIRC) soufflé muffins. They're egg-based and cooked in muffin tins, savoury or neutral so you can add veg or fruit. I'll try to remember to find the book tonight

Comment: Surely omlettes and other egg receipes (quiche-like dishes) are what your paleo one year old needs!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot simply leave out the sugar in a cake or pudding recipe, as it is quite important for the setting and the final texture. If you are looking for something which is made out of custard, has vegetables, and can be held in the fingers, you are describing a quiche. It can be made as mini-quiches too, for less messy eating.

Answer (score 1):

Tamagoyaki might fit the bill...no bread or flour. It is a Japanese omelette.  Here are [some pics.](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1&tbm=isch&q=japanese%20omelette&chips=q:japanese%20omelette,g_1:tamagoyaki&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPw8aG7JDcAhVrplkKHRWJDXQQ4lYIKCgA&biw=1366&bih=631&dpr=1)

Comment: That's a great suggestion.